# Locked route by cloud task using Google App Engine

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tasks

I have an application deployed on Google App Engine.
I call one route, and within that route, I launch a Cloud Task, the route completes successfully. However, when I make a request to another route, it only initiates after my task has finished.

Why does it have to wait? Something I in my app.yaml is missing ?

Thanks for help

I tried to change the app.yaml, adding workers or flex environment. It was working a bit in flex environment but full bugs. I have an application deployed on Google App Engine. I call one route, and within that route, I launch a Cloud Task; the route completes successfully. However, when I make a request to another route, it only initiates after my task has finished. Why does it have to wait?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.